# Transpose without PIVOT in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, join, pivot, transpose, cross-join

currently I am using pl/sql Developer(Oracle). I am told to convert a Row wise arranged data into columns but without the use of PIVOT. Since the Table I am working on dynamically changes, I am not able to use DECODE too.

```
 POLICY   SEQS   INVDATE     SUM(AMT) 
-------- ------ ----------- ----------
 policA   123    01-JAN-10     40
 policA   123    01-FEB-10     50
 policA   123    01-MAR-10     60
 policA   456    01-JAN-10    360
 policA   456    01-FEB-10    450
 policA   456    01-MAR-10    540
 policA   789    01-FEB-10   1000
 polcA    789    01-MAR-10   1000
```

I have to re-arrange the dates and the sum of amounts column wise. So that the Single Policy and Single SEQS will have the dates and its amount column wise in a line.

```
"POLICY","SEQS","INST1","INST1SUM","INST2","INST2SUM","INST3","INST3SUM"
"policA","123","01-JAN-10","40","01-FEB-10","50","01-MAR-10","60"
"policA","456","01-JAN-10","360","01-FEB-10","450","01-MAR-10","540"
"policA","789","01-FEB-10","1000","01-MAR-10","1000"
```

Some Policy might not be starting from Jan, so the INST1 must be from feb, INST2 must be Mar and INST3 and corresponding `INSTSUM` must be `NULL`.

Is there any way that this can be done using CROSS JOINS or using xml function?
Can I use xmlagg with alternative data (INST and SUM)?

I have done some research and am not able to solve this out. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: "Not able to use decode too" doesn't make any sense technically. And what do you mean the table changes dynamically?

Comment: You need to explain your scenario in more detail.  How many installments are there?  Are there a fixed number?  What determines the starting point?

Comment: Sorry for not providing enough detail. The number of Installments is not fixed, but the maximum is 12. The first Installment can be any month of the year. And what I had meant from "table changes dynamically" is that the Number of Installments changes from policies to policies and is not always 12. I have solved this issue and will post the Answer in some time. Thank you though.